# How to live video to facebook in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

This is my program to live video to Facebook

After the request, response code is 200, but the Facebook app does not start the live recording.

I check my Facebook wall on the web, I cannot found any new live video.

I also got a url from response

rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/xxxxxxx?ds=1&s_l=1&a=AaaDtiXrR_cranYA

And I tried to use vlc to open this url, but this url cannot be opened

How can I live video to Facebook

```
accessToken=AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
if(accessToken==null)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    return;
}

String fbUserId=Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId();
try {
    new GraphRequest(
            accessToken,
            "/"+fbUserId+"/live_videos",
            null,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.v("0",response.getRawResponse());
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You're making the post and getting back an RTMP URL... that's great, but nowhere in your code are you actually streaming to that URL.  In any case, you should read the policy on the Live API, which explicitly disallows streaming from a mobile device.  https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#liveAPI

Comment: Thanks Brad, But is there any way to send live stream on facebook from my android application, if yes then how can we do that?

Comment: @Mansuu.... Have you got anything for mobile app?

Comment: @Nisarg Not yet.

Comment: Any update? :) Im searching to stream from mobile app then get the live url ...